# What is Jack Sparrow's real name?

Tags: character, pirates-of-the-caribbean

Minor spoilers for Pirates of the Caribbean : Dead Men Tell No Tales ahead.

In the aforementioned movie, we learn from Captain Salazar that when he saw Captain Jack in the crow's nest of his ship, he looked like a bird and was given the nickname "Jack the sparrow". This begs the question - What is Jack's real last name? Is it mentioned in one of the other movies? I am not very familiar with the 4th movie, but I've seen all the others multiple times and can't recall hearing him referred to as another name.

Comment: As an interesting tidbit, the character was partially influenced by the real pirate Jack Ward, AKA Jackie Bird. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Ward

Comment: You mean Captain Jack Sparrow?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe it might possibly **Jack Teague** as his father, introduced in *Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End* and seen in *Pirates of the Caribbean: Stranger Tides*, is named **Edward Teague**

> Edward Teague was an infamous pirate captain in the Caribbean and father of Jack Sparrow. A legendary pirate in his own right, Teague occasionally re-appeared in the life of his son Jack, who followed in his buccaneering footsteps. Teague was an outlaw, but with an aristocratic bearing; a fearsome figure, but with unmistakable touches of sweetness and vulnerability.
>
> At some point in his career, Captain Teague became part of the Brethren Court, obtaining the title of Pirate Lord of Madagascar, and later Keeper of the Code. His candor, rigorous personal integrity, and uncompromising commitment to the Pirate Code had earned him the fear and respect not only of the other Pirate Lords, but of his son Jack as well. Although he appeared as a "stay at home" pirate, Teague would still be active in his later years. Teague would take part in the Brethren's stand against Cutler Beckett's Armada in the War Against Piracy, where they would choose the next Pirate King; and followed Jack in his search for the fabled Fountain of Youth, where he would warn his son of the perilous voyage.

Source: [Edward Teague](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Edward_Teague)

Now we know that Teague is Captain Teague's last name as in the Trivia section on the same page

> There was some controversy towards Teague's first name, as he was only referred to as "Captain Teague" in the POTC films. In the At World's End video game, while playing as him fighting enemies, Teague can be heard saying: "That's what you get for challenging Captain Edward Teague". The name was designated in the novel The Price of Freedom, though any first name has yet to be mentioned in the films.

So while it's not confirmed in the films that his first name is Edward it does confirm that Teague is his last name. since generally children receive their father's last name's like Bill Turner -> Will Turner and Weatherby Swann -> Elizabeth Swann logically this would mean Jack's last name would come from his father and thus be Jack Teague.

Comment: only if Teague is his real name. Sometimes there are names that created either mocking purposes or created upon person's actions, how he looks(Ex:Jack the Sparrow).. So it'd be Jack Teague if only Captain Teague's real name is Teague